# How to convert a Visualforce apex:pageMessages to be lightning style

Tags: visualforce, slds

During my working on converting existing pages to be lightning experience style (as known as slds style). One of the challenges I have faced is to convert `<apex:pageMessages/>` . Usually the controller side of code is something like below:

```
public class ConvertPageMessagesController{
    public ConvertPageMessagesController(){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter Account name'));
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Account number'));
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please enter Account phone'));
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Please enter Account site'));
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Please enter Account industry'));
    }
}
```

There are definitely walkaround on this. I can use a page_message and a serverity_level property and check the page status and the page message and use front-end code to handle the logic. But the code will inevitable be long and tedious. Is there a good way of handling this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what I do:

Class used by all my controllers:

VF Messages Abstract:

```
public abstract class VF_Messages_Abstract {


    public void createError(ApexPages.Severity s, String message) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(
                New ApexPages.Message(
                        s, string.escapeSingleQuotes(message.escapeJava())
                )
        );

    }

    /**@description Indicates if a custom message is present*/
    public boolean hasMessages {
        get {
             return ApexPages.hasMessages();
        }
    }

    /**@description The custom error message */
    public String errorMessage {
        get {
            if (hasMessages) {
                return ApexPages.getMessages()[0].getDetail();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    /**@description The type of message: 'error' or 'success' */
    public string alertType {
        get {
            if (hasMessages) {
                return ApexPages.getMessages()[0].getSeverity() == ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM ? 'success' : 'error';
            }

            return 'error';
        }
        private set;
    }



}
```

***All controller for VF extend this class***

Then in my vf pages I use the following:

**Messages Toast**

```
    <!-- ERROR ALERT DIV -->
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="msg_block" style="display: none;">
        <div id="err_wrapper"
             class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--{!alertType} slds-theme--alert-texture"
             role="alert">
            <h2>
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true"
                         class="slds-icon icon-text-email slds-icon--small slds-m-right--x-small">
                        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#' + if(alertType = 'success','check','ban'))}"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <span id="err_text"></span>
                </div>
            </h2>
        </div>

    </apex:outputPanel>
```

**Helper Panel**

```
        <!--APEX VARIABLES DIV-->
        <apex:outputPanel id="post_processing">

            <script>

                var hasMessages = {!hasMessages};
                var errorMessage = "{!errorMessage}";

                checkMessages();

            </script>

        </apex:outputPanel>
```

**Check Messages Code (Using jQuery)**

```
function checkMessages() {
    if (hasMessages) {
        $('#err_text').html(errorMessage);
        $('[id$=msg_block]').show();
    } else {
        $('[id$=msg_block]').hide();
    }

}
```

My buttons, action functions, etc rerender the `post_processing` and `msg_block`

***Creating an error*** In the controller when I catch or want to display an error I simply:

```
createError(ApexPages.Severity.[ERROR | CONFIRM],YOURMESSAGEHERE);
```

This allows me to control the messages, when to display it and which theme to show.

**Note:** The `xmlns=` on the `div` containing the SVG is a MUST as if you try to rerender without it the page will simply stall. Important trick to remember for anytime you are re rendering a container containing an SLDS SVG

If you need a example all put together let me know.

End result is (Error):

[image]

Or (Confirm)

[image]

I also have implemented a way to pass messages between transactions so if you need to say DML on button click and then Callout oncomplete of button click, if there was an error in the first step, when the second step happens it does not clear the message like it normally would (not shown in code)

Comment: Thank you for sharing, Eric. I will post that method in my blog, too, if you don't mind. It has a bit more code, but definitely has two obvious advantageous: 1, can work on multiple types of messages: toast, alert, dialog. 2, don't need to have the assumption the implementation of VF is unchanged.

Comment: @LanceShi - I do not mind at all. Hope it helps someone. I have not completely made the transition yet to Lightning so I am getting good at working with VF and SLDS (at least I think I am which may be worse :) )

Comment: @AdrianLarson - No idea, she was there when I created the DE org from salesforce. So (I think) she is in all DE orgs created from the Env Hub. She is a contact on United Oil & Gas, Singapore. I'll crop it just in case

Comment: @AdrianLarson yea not for this answer. It essentially hides the modal loader/spinner. I'll remove it to remove confusion

Comment: I wonder how hard it is to scale this solution for an arbitrary number of messages. Finally getting my feet wet in this arena.

Comment: Good question. Never had a reason to as only cared about the latest message. Maybe simply add a method to gather all the page messages into a string of your choice then set the error message to that string?

Answer (score 12):

Eric's answer inspired me to build a more generic tool that can support an arbitrary number of page messages of any severity.

## Code

#### Controller

```
public class ToastBuilderController
{
    public String getMessageJSON() { return JSON.serialize(getSafeMessages()); }
    public List<PageMessage> getSafeMessages()
    {
        List<PageMessage> messages = new List<PageMessage>();
        for (ApexPages.Message message : ApexPages.getMessages())
            messages.add(new PageMessage(message));
        return messages;
    }
}
```

#### Serializable PageMessage

```
global class PageMessage
{
    global final String summary, detail;
    global final String sprite, theme;
    global final ApexPages.Severity severity;
    global PageMessage(Exception e)
    {
        this(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, e.getMessage());
    }
    global PageMessage(ApexPages.Message message)
    {
        this(message.getSeverity(), message.getSummary(), message.getDetail());
    }
    global PageMessage(ApexPages.Severity severity, String summary, String detail)
    {
        this.severity = severity;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.detail = detail;

        String s = String.valueOf(severity);
        this.sprite = sprites.get(s);
        this.theme = themes.get(s);
    }
    global PageMessage(ApexPages.Severity severity, String summary)
    {
        this(severity, summary, null);
    }

    static final Map<String, String> themes = new Map<String, String>
    {
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL) => 'error',
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR) => 'error',
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING) => 'warning',
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM) => 'success'
    };
    static final Map<String, String> sprites = new Map<String, String>
    {
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL) => 'ban',
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR) => 'warning',
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING) => 'warning',
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM) => 'success',
        String.valueOf(ApexPages.Severity.INFO) => 'info'
    };
}
```

#### Toast Builder Component

Probably should move the JS to a `Static Resource` but I was trying to whip this together quickly.

```
<apex:component controller="ToastBuilderController">
    <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    (function (D, w) {
        "use strict";
        var T = w.ToastBuilder = w.ToastBuilder || {};
        T.sprites = {
            "success": "{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS214, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#success')}",
            "error": "{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS214, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#error')}",
            "info": "{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS214, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#info')}"
        };
        T.getMessages = function () {
            return JSON.parse("{!JSENCODE(messageJSON)}");
        };
        T.clear = function () {
            while (T.targetDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
                T.targetDiv.removeChild(T.targetDiv.lastChild);
            };
        };
        T.buildToasts = function (messages) {
            if (!messages) messages = T.getMessages();
            T.clear();
            messages.forEach(function (message) {
                T.buildToast(message);
            });
        };
        T.buildToast = function (message) {
            var toast = D.createElement("div");
            toast.className = "slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--alert-texture";
            if (message.theme) toast.className += " slds-theme--" + message.theme; 
            toast.setAttribute("role", "alert");

            var innerDiv = toast.appendChild(D.createElement("h2"))
                .appendChild(D.createElement("div"));
            innerDiv.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
            innerDiv.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
            innerDiv.appendChild(D.createElement("span"))
                .appendChild(D.createTextNode(message.summary));

            var svg = innerDiv.appendChild(D.createElement("svg"));
            svg.className = "slds-icon icon-text-email slds-icon--small slds-m-right--x-small";
            svg.setAttribute("aria-hidden", true);

            var use = svg.appendChild(D.createElement("use"));
            use.setAttribute("xlink:href", T.sprites[message.sprite]);

            T.targetDiv.appendChild(toast);
        };
        T.addError = function (message) {
            T.clear();
            T.buildToast({
                theme: "error", sprite: "warning", summary: message
            });
        };
        T.confirm = function (message) {
            T.clear();
            T.buildToast({
                theme: "success", sprite: "success", summary: message
            });
        };
        D.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            T.targetDiv = D.getElementById("messages");
            T.buildToasts();
            Object.freeze(T);
        });
    }(document, window));
    </script>
</apex:component>
```

## Usage

#### RemoteAction

```
(function (w) {
    "use strict"
    MyRemotingController.doSomething("Some Parameter", function (result, event) {
        if (event.status) {
            if (result.length === 0) {
                // success handling
            } else {
                w.ToastBuilder.buildToasts(result);
                // other error handling
            }
        } else {
            w.ToastBuilder.addError(event.message);
        }
    });
}(window));
```

#### Remote Objects

```
(function (w) {
    "use strict";
    new SObjectModel.Contact().update(
        ["{!Contact.Id}"], {"SomeField__c": someValue}, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                w.ToastBuilder.addError(error);
                // other error handling
            } else {
                // success handling
            }
        }
    );
}(window));
```

#### ApexPages

If you use the standard approach to adding page messages to the page, calling `buildToasts` will take the `messageJSON` property and use it to build toasts corresponding to `ApexPages.getMessages()`.

(Controller)

```
try
{
    // do stuff
}
catch (SomeException e)
{
    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
}
```

(Page)

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doStuff}" oncomplete="ToastBuilder.buildToasts()" />
```

Comment: var T = w.ToastBuilder = w.ToastBuilder || {}; Is this one a type?

Comment: The `T` is just shorthand, and `w.ToastBuilder` is just a namespace to group a few functions together. Not sure exactly what you're asking? You are not able to reference `T` outside the closure, but `ToastBuilder` is added to the `window` (referenced as `w` within the closure).

Comment: I mean should it be just var T = w.ToastBuilder || {}; ? Why there is an extra = w.ToastBuilder = w.ToastBuilder || {}?

Comment: How do you handle messages when one action calls a second action and the message from first action needs displayed? Or does it do that. In vanilla vf the message would've cleared in second action. Use case. First action dml second action callout if first ok, dml if first not ok. That was the point of my persistent message. Great work. Makes me feel like a newbie

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. It's a way of checking if it's already been defined on the page. In other words, if there is already a `ToastBuilder` on the `window`, use that, otherwise instantiate a new empty object.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I get your point here. But I still think var T = w.ToastBuilder || {}; will do the trick. Because if w.ToastBuilder is null or undefined, it will generate a new class based on this.

Comment: @LanceShi But if you do that, `ToastBuilder` will *never* be added to the `window` and you will not be able to reference *any* of this code outside the closure. If anything, you would reduce it to `var T = w.ToastBuilder = {}` and remove the check for an existing reference on the `window`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Adrian. Now I understand that. This is very awesome code. However, there are still several things in my mind can be improved (or maybe I don't understand it): 1. I don't see getMessageJSON() and getSafeMessages() used elsewhere in your above code. And I don't think you need to call them in your use case. 2. w = window is only true in your IIFE, but you are assuming it everywhere. 3. Probably a template engine will help here? 4. We might be able to adjust the code to build more than one type of page message: toast, alert, dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the current approach I have found and used. But I am open to any other suggestions.

The idea and code originally is coming from: https://vishnuvaishnav.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/convert-standard-page-messages-in-lightning-design-system/

I have also written a blog about this idea at: http://sfdcinpractice.com/index.php/2016/11/22/convert-apexpagemessages-slds-style/

Basically, it is a little bit hacking into the Visualforce page by changing the style class into slds ones.

**The css:**

```
<style>
.msgIcon {
    display: none!important
}
.customMessage * {
    color: #fff!important
}
.customMessage {
    margin: 5px 0!important;
    max-width: 1280px;
    opacity: 1!important;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.message {
    opacity: .1
}
</style>
```

**The Javascript code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       overridePageMessages();    
    });

    function overridePageMessages(){    
        var textureEffect = '';
        //Uncomment below line for texture effect on page messages
        //textureEffect = 'slds-theme--alert-texture';

        $('.warningM3').addClass('slds-notify slds-notify--toast slds-theme--warning customMessage '+textureEffect);          
        $('.confirmM3').addClass('slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--success  customMessage '+textureEffect);    
        $('.errorM3').addClass('slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error customMessage '+textureEffect);                  
        $('.infoM3').addClass('slds-notify slds-notify--toast customMessage '+textureEffect);    

        $('.errorM3').removeClass('errorM3'); 
        $('.confirmM3').removeClass('confirmM3'); 
        $('.infoM3').removeClass('infoM3');   
        $('.warningM3').removeClass('warningM3');  
    }
</script>
```

Add the script to document.ready() or the oncomplete function.

Comment: Your Javascript code assumes jQuery is present, but you don't even need jQuery for any of this functionality.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, you are right. It is definitely okay to use vanilla javascript and it is not hard to convert into vanilla javascript as well. But it doesn't hurt to use jQuery in most cases and it is a bit easier to write. I will include a pure javascript version in my blog.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you should at the very least use `jQuery.noConflict()` and probably also use [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to protect the global scope.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I am not a big fan of using jQuery.noConflict(). But since you have mentioned, I will definitely take a look at it and learn more about the benefits of it. Thank you for pointing it out.